Windows 10 suddenly unable to start. Recovery tools not working and file recovery needed
I have a Dell Inspiron laptop with Windows 10. Today, it was working normally when suddenly the internet went out. I thought it was the whole network since it usually is, but I realized it was just this computer. I figured a restart would fix it. However, upon booting up again, the computer immediately went into automatic recovery mode, and then it said Windows automatic recovery couldn’t fix the problem. I restarted several times.
So, I looked up what to do in advanced options and tried running some recommended commands. I tried sfc /scannow, and it said it was unable to complete the operation. I then did chkdsk /r c:, which, after 7 hours of scanning, found no errors.
The last thing I tried was bootrec /rebuildbcd. It said, “identified Windows installations: 0. The operation completed successfully.” What do you think the issue is here? I’m fine with reinstalling Windows, but I want to recover my files. I have the main SSD on C: and also a 2 TB hard drive in the laptop. Ideally, if I could just recover the PC and boot into it, that would be great, too, but I know that may not be possible.
Update:
I have a major update. I was trying out some more commands and realized windows is not finding almost any of its system files or directories including c:\boot so I just did a dir c:\ out of curiosity, and the contents of c: is actually all the personal files on my 2 tb hd (D:), none of which are system files. So then I did dir D: and it shows all of the C: system files including the Windows folder. Somehow the drive letters got switched around? Do I just rename the drive letters? This is so weird. All the files appear intact

I have never in 25 years recovered from the type of boot failure you describe.  Your boot configuration data (BCD) is most likely corrupt.  The fact you have not been able to detect your Windows installation is evident.  Without being able to verify if there are any corrupt system files, you are left in a position where my suggestion would be to extract what data you can.  Once you do that, replace the drive and reinstall Windows. chkdsk does not identify a failing drive, only if there are problems with the file system.  A failing HDD does not always result in detectable problems with the FS

Just to be clear, rebuilding the boot configuration data, and the command returning identified Windows installations: 0 means the command did NOT rebuild the data.  The boot configuration data is not on a volume that typically has a disk letter, which is likely the reason, the installation was NOT detected.

How would I go about extracting the data? I’ve never done this before. And could I reinstall windows on the same drive or does it have to be a whole new ssd?

Here is someplace to start regarding data recovery: https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device

You should definitely purchase a new drive, set the faulty one aside and perform recovery operations on it after you have a fresh Windows install working on the new drive. Don't write any data to the faulty drive, because that WILL overwrite the data you want to recover.

@tonyd1234 - I would use hardware to duplicate the data on the drive.  I would then use an external adapter to connect the drive with the duplicate data. I would not mount only the copy of data I have determined is vital.  I would evaluate my risk factor in doing this myself or sending the drive to a data recovery company with tools not often found in the wild.  These tools will frequently communicate at a hardware level to scan and export the data on the drive. 8 hours to check the drive only makes sense on the largest mechanical drives.

I have a major update. I was trying out some more commands and realized windows is not finding almost any of it’s system files or directories, so I just did a dir c:\ out of curiosity, and the contents of c: is actually all the personal files on my 2 tb hd (D:), none of which are system files. So then I did dir D: and it shows all of the C: system files including the Windows folder. Somehow the drive letters got switched around? Do I just rename the drive letters? This is so weird. All the files appear intact.

The safest thing to do is immediately make a full drive image on separate media before trying any repair. Sometimes attempts to fix a damaged file system cause further damage and loss of files. *After making an image, you can try rebooting once again, reinstalling Windows form ISO, etc, without fear of losing data.

@tonyd1234 - That is normal while within WinRE.

@tonyd1234 The drive names are good that way, dont worry about it. However, this means your commands should be aimed at the D: drive. Your sfc command will look something like sfc /scannow /offwindir=d:\windows /offbootdir=d:\ and your chkdsk should be chkdsk d: /r

@Silbee thanks fir that advice. I ran sfc and it said there is a repair that requires a reboot, so I restarted but it still didn’t work. I ran sfc again and it said the same thing again. I did chkdsk and it said that it fixed some file system errors but nothing changed. The bootrec commands seem impossible to direct to a different disk.

@tonyd1234 bootrec automaticly scans all volumes. It looks like you'll have to go one of the options above. Take a backup or drive image from the broken drive to safeguard your data and then you can chose to play some more fixing or just reinstall.

If you can, disable or disconnect the 2TB secondary drive and reboot. If somehow the system got confused about the drive order, taking out the secondary drive should at least get you back into Windows. From there you can proceed with whatever processes you need for validating the drive setup and making sure your computer knows the larger drive needs to be secondary.
